# Meaning of "all" here

Tags: american-english, idioms

I was reading a novel and came across this line "Magnus was all for staying here" . What does it mean here?

Answer (score 2):

It means that Magnus has absolutely no objections and completely agrees to do it and/or completely supports this idea.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+for